# How to persist some contents from a list of entities

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I am wondering if there is a "proper" way to achieve the following using EclipseLink. I have a list of objects

```
List<MyType> newList
```

and upon startup of my application I want to check whether ALL of its contents are already persisted (during a previous deploy of my app) and if not, I want to persist all new ones.
Currently I am fetching already persisted entities like this:

```
List<Video> oldList = em.createQuery("select v from MyType v").getResultList();
```

So I have two lists and ideally I would want to reach a point at which all contents of newList are persisted.

Note that oldList will always be a sublist of newList, in the sense that newList will always contain at least what oldList contains.

Thanks

Comment: So you're not happy with your current design?

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems for me, you've just posted a solution for your problem :-)

If you are able to get the `oldList` during startup of your app, than you might just iterate over the `newList` and for each object check if `oldList.contains(yourObject)`.

If it doesn't - persist it; if it does - just move to the next element.

You just need to be sure that you have properly implemented equals() for your objects, as it will be used to check for equality.

HTH.